# Add data attribute to element and dynamically add value from class name

Tags: jquery

I want to add a data-attribute to an element and dynamically give it the same value as the class name.

I have used this script to do the same from an elements´string - but I want to pass the value from the class name instead, and not sure how to do that.

Script:

```
$('.newgroup').attr('data-price', function() {
var text = $(this).text();
return parseInt(text, 10); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="newgroup">/div>
```

Should looks like this:

```
<div class="newgroup" data-price="newgroup">>/div>
```

Comment: _same value as the class name_? so why parsing the text of it.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/Lvmte8ap/) only if only class exists [demo1](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/Lvmte8ap/1/) if you have other class you can play inside function to target which class you want

Comment: `$(".newgroup").attr("data-price", "newgroup")` I think this will be enough for you.

Comment: just use...    return this.className;   .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/A6BXk/54/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write the following:

```
$(".newgroup").attr("data-price", $('.newgroup').attr('class'));
```

**.attr** sets the attribute value and **.attr('class')** returns the **classname**

See the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bTtdTNsqJK9jOTsnRq6p?p=preview)

As you can see in the screenshot, the **attribute** is added:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the following to assign the `attribute`, the value as the *class-name*:

```
$('.newgroup').attr('data-price', function() {
    return $(this).attr('class');
});
```

Refer to the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/nv3h7tue/).